# Can't open file using QStandardPaths

Tags: c++, qt, file, io

I am trying to create a program that opens a file when I push a button. I have created a `QStandardPath` in the header file. I then append /myfile.txt to the end of it and try to open it. I am just starting out with Qt and would like some advice.

dialog.h:

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QStandardPaths>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QString Location = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation);
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private slots:
    void on_btn_Read_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QFile>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::on_btn_Read_clicked()
{
    QFile myFile(Location.append("/myfile.txt"));

    if(!myFile.exists())
    {
        qDebug() << "File does not exist. attempting to create. . .";
        if (myFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text)){
            qDebug() << "created :]";
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "not created :[";
        }
    }
    myFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Is the result of `qDebug() << myFile.fileName();` really exist ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? Do you want me to try that?  I don't currently have that in my code.

Comment: Yes, I tried to tell that please check it the debug window. Write it after the `QFile` instantiation. And then check if the displayed path is really exist.

Comment: this is my debug:

"C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Roaming/File_IO_Practice/myfile.txt"
File does not exist. attempting to create. . .
not created :[

Comment: Do you have write permission ? Try creating a file there.

Comment: I just created a file in the roaming directory manually. However I noticed the File_IO_Practice file is just a file. It is not a file FOLDER. It shows up as a little white page icon instead of a yellow folder icon. Does this have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if the given directory is exist. If not then you need to create the full path with for example:

```
QDir().mkpath( /**/ );
```

And you can create a file only after this.

```
QFile file( filename );
if ( file.opne( /**/ ) )
{
    // ...
}
```

*(But all of these things are only after you are sure that you have permission.)*